# ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections'

Tags: python

can anyone help me out of this error, please?

```
(env) C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TabulaPy>excalibur initdb
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 15, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\util.py", line 14, in <module>
    from contextlib import contextmanager
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 5, in <module>
    from collections import deque
ImportError: cannot import name 'deque' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: You didn't share any code, so it's hard to say - but you probably created something called `collections` which shadows the library. Please share the relevant bits of code for more of an answer

Comment: Im trying to run the following command to start excalibur ：

Comment: $ excalibur initdb
$ excalibur webserver

Comment: @Jhenylyn Kindly provide a snapshot of code so we can debug.

Comment: I have installed already the  Excalibur and Ghostscript

Comment: @Jhenylyn Please add the code here. Your Excalibur or Ghostscript might require another library to be present which isn't available.

Comment: This is the only commands to be execute after intalling excalibur                                        
 $ excalibur initdb
$ excalibur webserver

Comment: @Jhenylyn kindly provide the code block.

Comment: I'm going to do the same thing as what explained here https://www.codestudyblog.com/sfb2002b1/0225161243.html

Comment: This error indicates that something has gone wrong with loading extension modules. `collections.deque` is loaded into the `collections` namespace from the `_collections` C helper extension module. If `collections` cannot load `_collections`, it [ignores the error](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L41-L44) and continues without `collections.deque`, which would lead to the observed exception when something tries to use `collections.deque`.

Comment: what should i do to the collections module please

Comment: That said, we can't tell *why* something went wrong with extension module loading. Also, it sounds like you're trying to run a program someone else wrote, rather than looking for help with writing your own code. We handle questions about writing programs, not running them.

Comment: i wanted to try that out , do u have any idea on how to run excalibur ?

Comment: i can use Camelot but i needed a GUI so i will use excalibur